# Assigning an array of Objects in another Constructor, where the Class contains const emember

Tags: c++, arrays, class, constructor, constants

I've looked around and only found a solution for either problem, which conflicts with the other.
I have
class A with some const member and other members that need to be initialized
class B with some constructor and a 2D array of A's

like this:

```
class A {
public:
  A();
  A(int t, int u);
  const int x = 5;

private:
  int _t;
  int _u;
}

class B {
public:
  B();
  A a[50][500];
}

A::A() {
  //nothing here
}

A::A(int t, int u) {
  _t = t;
  _u = u;
}

B::B() {
  for (int i=0; i<50; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<500; j++)
      a[i][j] = A(i, j);
}
```

Now, this doesn't work because A has a const member, so the assignment fails because all the a's have already been default constructed, I obviously don't want to code 25000 initializer values in the member initializer list of B so that is out of the question.

I need the default initializer because otherwise the constructor of B will throw an error that i can't default initialize the array so i need some way to reassign the array with a newly constructed object of A.
How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want?

```
class A {
public:
  A();
  A(int t, int u);
  const int x = 5;

  A& operator=(const A& a);
private:
  int _t;
  int _u;
};

class B {
public:
  B();
  A a[50][500];
};

A::A() {
  //nothing here
}

A& A::operator=(const A& a) {
    _t = a._t;
    _u = a._u;
}

A::A(int t, int u) {
  _t = t;
  _u = u;
}

B::B() {
  for (int i=0; i<50; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<500; j++)
      a[i][j] = A(i, j);
}
```

You are just missing the = operator

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid default-initializing your array, you can use `std::vector<std::vector<A>>` and populate it in B's constructor :

```cpp
class A {
public:
  A(t, u);
  const int x = 5;

private:
  int _t;
  int _u;
}

class B {
public:
  B();
  std::vector<std::vector<A>> a;
}

A::A(t, u) {
  _t = t;
  _u = u;
}

B::B()
: a(50) { // a will contain 50 empty rows
  for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
    a[i].reserve(500); // allocates enough space in each row for at least 500 elements
    for(int j=0; j<500; j++)
      a[i].emplace_back(i, j); // constructs value in-place using given arguments
  }
}
```

Note that you don't need A's empty-parameter constructor anymore, so I have removed it.